# Where should xt.vim be put on osX?

Tags: vim, osx

Cracking xDebug open, finally and looking to add the vim formatting file from [xDebug.org](http://xdebug.org/docs/execution_trace).

It says to "copy" the file to `~/.vim/syntax`. But such a directory doesn't exist on osx 10.6.

I don't see `xt.vim` on the computer either, but did find it on [github](https://github.com/derickr/xdebug.org/blob/master/html/files/xt.vim).

`which vim` returns `/usr/bin/vim`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the file to `~/.vim/syntax/xt.vim`, and ensure that you have `:syntax on` in your `~/.vimrc`.

To edit a file with that syntax highlighting, use

```
:edit +setf\ xt the-file
```

or define a *filetype detection* rule, cp. `:help new-filetype`.

Comment: Thank you. It looks like all the `vim` files are in `/usr/share/vim/vim72/`. This includes `vimrc_example`. Are you directing me to make a directory at `~/`? Should I copy the contents of `/usr/share/vim/vim72/` there? And if so, what does the `.` mean, please? Calling `ls` on `~/` for example does not show `.bash_profile`. Can you help clarify.

Comment: Yes, please put your custom Vim files at `~/.vim` (creating dirs if necessary); the `/usr/share/vim` location is a system location; never modify that; you'll lose changes during upgrades or reinstalls!

Comment: The leading `.` makes the file hidden; this is customary (on Unix and OS X) for configuration, so that it doesn't distract you. `ls -a` shows those files.

Comment: I don't have the credibility to bump you up yet. Thank you. Would you recommend copying all of the files in `vim72` or just adding pieces as needed?

Comment: You don't need to copy them; Vim looks in both locations (see `:h 'runtimepath'`). I would recommend looking for a newer Vim package (if available); Vim 7.2 is from 2008!

Comment: ok. will upgrade. where can i look for info on `:edit`, `:h`, etc. Are they `unix` or `vim` commands? When I tried `:edit +setf\ xt whatever-file` from the CL it returns `-bash: :edit: command not found` and when trying `vim :edit +setf\ xt whatever-file` it created a file called `:edit`.

Comment: Commands that start with `:` are given in Vim; if you're new to Vim, try `vimtutor` (in the shell), or any of the many Internet resources, e.g. http://vimcasts.org/